# rosserial compile error: missing rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with ros indigo.
I've dowloaded the rosserial source from git
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial
When I try to compile in catkin_ws I get the message that rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h is missing (see below).
Now I'm wondering where this file is. It's not in the repository.
Where can I get it?
...

```
[  4%] Building CXX object rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/src/serial_node.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_socket_node.dir/src/socket_node.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pat/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server/include/rosserial_server/serial_session.h:43:0,
                 from /home/pat/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server/src/serial_node.cpp:40:
/home/pat/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server/include/rosserial_server/session.h:44:38: fatal error: rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include <rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h>
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/pat/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server/src/socket_node.cpp:40:0:
/home/pat/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server/include/rosserial_server/session.h:44:38: fatal error: rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include <rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h>
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190110/rosserial-compile-error:-missing-rosserial_msgs/topicinfo.h/) by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-14**:
You cloned the complete repository right?

**Comment by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on 2014-08-14**:
I assume. I used git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial in catkin_ws/src

**Comment by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on 2014-08-17**:
Issue disapear due to fix https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this is a bug in rosserial_server; the build file is missing a dependency between the header generation and the compile step which is causing them to be run out of order.

This sort of thing will sometimes go away if you run it enough, but you should really file a bug on the rosserial issue tracker about it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1